# how to check grid view data row have value and if have value then formate with date time

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have grid view. which shows records that Product table contains here i just want to using combine logic like :

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty((DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReleaseDate", "{0:dd / MM / yyyy}")) ? " - " : Eval("ReleaseDate", "{0}"))%>'></asp:Label>
```

this logic not works and not putting - if data row have no value.

please help me...

Comment: what kind of out you want from this logic

Comment: here i just also formate ReleaseDate column and also check if null then set '-' character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("ReleaseDate")== DBNull.Value ? "-" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReleaseDate","{0:dd / MM / yyyy}")) %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

you forget + sigh to add both of them

Made an edit see if this work

```
runat="server" Text='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReleaseDate", "{0:dd / MM / yyyy}")) ? " - " : Eval("ReleaseDate", "{0}"))%>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: it's give me compile time error like : Syntax error, ':' expected

Comment: well i use this logic : <%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty((DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReleaseDate", "{0:dd / MM / yyyy}")) ? " - " : Eval("ReleaseDate", "{0}"))%> but it's give me error like ) expected

Comment: you forget one of the closing brackets

Comment: it's works but it's give me date like '02/04/2013 12:00:00 AM'